# Convert.ChangeType to produce an array of concrete type elements, not objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, type-conversion

Struggling with the following problem. I have an attribute that defines the name of the key in the database table. Using reflection, I initialize the value of a property or a field with that attribute. Everything is great until I define my property as an array:

```
[ConfigurationKey("TestArray")]
public int[] Array { get; set; }
```

Assuming that values stored in the table are comma-delimited strings, I am using the following to create an array:

```
return valueString.Split(',').Select(s => Convert.ChangeType(s, memberType.GetElementType())).ToArray();
```

This does create an array of elements but only array of Objects. As a result when I use FieldInfo or PropertyInfo to set a value, it throws with the exception "Cannot assign `Object[]` to `Int32[]`".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well given that `Convert.ChangeType` is declared to return `Object`, I don't think this is particularly surprising. `ToArray()` will create an array with the same element type as the input sequence, and `Select` is going to return an `IEnumerable<object>` in this case.

One option is to call `Cast` (and then `ToArray`) using reflection. To be honest, it's probably going to be easiest to put everything into a single generic method, and call *that* by reflection:

```
public static T[] ParseToArray<T>(string valueString)
{
    return valueString.Split(',')
                      .Select(s => (T) Convert.ChangeType(s, typeof(T))
                      .ToArray();
}
```

Then you'd need:

```
Type t = memberType.GetElementType();
// Use the type declaring ParseToArray here
MethodInfo methodDefinition = typeof(...).GetMethod("ParseToArray");
MethodInfo method = methodDefinition.MakeGenericMethod(t);
object array = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { valueString });
```

Comment: Cast doesn't except a type parameter unfortunately, i.e. I can't write .Cast<memberType.GetElementType()>().

Comment: @Schultz9999: That's why I said you'd have to call it by reflection. See my edit.

Comment: hmm, I see. That gave me an idea. If all my arrays are primitive, I can use the similar approach to get "Parse" method and execute it thru reflection for each split, right?

Comment: thanks a lot Jon. Your answer is right. Parse I mentioned doesn't work because Invoke return Object, which brings me to square one.